# How do I avoid the automatic search from a jQuery UI Autocomplete component?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Right now if I initialize my component like this:

```
$('#foo').autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 1,
    source: self.loadUsers.bind(self),
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).autocomplete('widget').hide();
        var selected = ui.item;
        var element = selected.element;
        // more stuff here
    },
    focus: function() { return false; },
    open: function() { console.log('Opening menu...'); }
})
```

It will perform the search (and correctly call `loadUsers`) each time the text in #foo is changed. `focus` and `open` events will work as normal.

**What I want to avoid is, actually, avoid triggering the search in that way**. I want to perform the search only when ENTER (keyCode 13) is pressed (or released, better). Right now both parts are working: performing search when pressing enter, which is done by this event handler for a keyup:

```
function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        var input = $("#foo"); // perhaps $(this) could do the job?
        input.autocomplete('search');
    }
}
```

**BUT** I want to remove the call to search from regular keystrokes/text-changes. I tried calling `.off('keyup keydown keypress change')` but somehow it did not work: each time I type in the textbox the suggestions appear.

**ALSO** specifying `disabled: true` as option does not work, since when I do that, even when the search method is only called when I press ENTER (which is the intended functionality) and the list of elements is correctly retrieved... the UI list is not populated with the result nor shown.

How can I make this one work?

Answer (score 0):

Found it for future readers:

You have an autocompletesearch event which you can handle like this when initializing (or binding with ´on´ later to ´autocompletesearch´ event):

```
search: function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent) {
        // comes from an AUTOMATIC (orevent-triggered) .search,
        //   instead of coming from the manual call to .autocomplete('search').
        // so we must ban it.
        return false;
    }
},
```

Such event is triggered when `.autocomplete('search'[, someValueHere])` is called or when standard events (keydown, input) are fired on the input component. In this latter case, the `event` (1st) parameter in the handler for `autocompletesearch` will be an event having a field `.originalEvent`, while in the former case (manually invoking the search method), the event will not have such field.

So you can return false when such field is present.